# Running logstash via central NFS location

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-file

I have configured an ELK Server and all there component are on the same servers.. Though, i'm trying to pick my `logstash-syslog.conf` from the central point that's based on NFS so i dont need to Install `logstash` on each client..

1) My `logstash-syslog.conf`  file

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/var/log/messages" ]
    type => "test"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "test" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
output {
        if "automount" in [message] {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "oida-elk:9200"
                #index => "newmsglog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "msg"
        }
        stdout {}
}
}
```

2) When I'm running the on the clients to get the data it start the thread and just stucks there ..

```
[Myclient1 =~] # $ /home/data/logstash-6.0.0/bin/logstash -f /home/data/logstash-6.0.0/conf.d/ --path.data=/tmp/klm
```

3) after running the above command its shows below logs and then do not proceed anywhere...

```
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,014][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://oida-elk:9200/"}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,078][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,085][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,101][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//oida-elk:9200"]}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,297][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2ea3b180@/home/data/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290 run>"}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,746][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2018-03-05T21:20:51,800][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
```

Please help / suggest anything ..

Answer (score 0):

can you run the logtash validation using -t flag.
Also you have to pass full path to file when using the -f flag.
Can you tail on the file to see if it has newer entries coming.
I would like to add that For reading files over  to logtash using filebeat is a better choice.

Comment: tnx somehow there was a small typo on the config , now its working .